# accessing table in html collection

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, code-injection, htmlcollection

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxv22.png)

[image]

Above are 2 screenshots. One is of the console in the browser and the other is some javascript I'm injecting into an iframe. When I print the table that I got by its classname, it says that it's an HTML Collection. But when I try and access the contents with the .item() method, it some out null, even though I can clearly see there's information indexed at 0.

Any help?

EDIT:
Added these screenshots to show what I'm trying to access

[image]
[image]

Comment: how do you want to access your table?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```js
var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
  console.log("Result ",x)
```

```html
<p>A P element.</p>
<p class="myclass">Another P element.</p>
<p class="myclass">A third P element.</p>
```

try table.item(0)
check out this below website
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_htmlcollection_item.asp

Comment: I'm alerting table.item(0) and it comes up null

Comment: post your html code .may be your class name is not correct.because i can see your htmlcollection array is empty

Comment: I don't want to post the HTML code because this is for a class assignment. I don't want to give away too much information that might count towards academic misconduct. I did update my question to include screenshots of what I'm saying. perhaps the collection is empty, but there is definitely information to be accessed